# How to convert a string color to its hex code or RGB value?

Tags: php, colors, hex

I would like to create some sort of function where you pass in a string such as "yellow" or "green" and it returns its hex code or the range of hex codes that greens or yellows fit into.

Is this possible in PHP? If not possible, I am willing to try anything else that can do this!

Comment: it is possible in PHP, if you have a database that contain all these colors. So, you just have to get that database somewhere

Comment: You may want to use [the 16 basic colours defined in the HTML standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.5).

Comment: you can find all color names and their hex value on this site:
http://www.iconbazaar.com/color_tables/lepihce.html with some regexp it should be possible to use this to build a "database" of any kind. EDIT: http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/453-color-names-and-rgb-values-with-wide-browser-support/ also a nice list, seems to be easier to import to eg. csv.

Comment: I think the easiest solution is to build your own look-up table for the colors you plan on having as inputs. Also allowing the hex color code as an input will allow the user to enter in any color they want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to my knowledge to convert [HTML color names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_color_names) or [CSS color names](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_colornames.asp) to their Hex or RGB value in PHP. You'd have to create a map that knows the names (see Wiki article).

Someone has done this work for you already:

- [http://psoug.org/snippet/CSS_Colornames_to_RGB_values_415.htm](https://web.archive.org/web/20200221133333/psoug.org/snippet/CSS_Colornames_to_RGB_values_415.htm)

Excerpt:

```
$Colors  =  ARRAY( 
    "black"=>array( "red"=>0x00,  "green"=>0x00,  "blue"=>0x00), 
    "maroon"=>array( "red"=>0x80,  "green"=>0x00,  "blue"=>0x00), 
    // ...
    // more colors inbetween
    // ...
    "wheat"=>array( "red"=>0xF5,  "green"=>0xDE,  "blue"=>0xB3), 
    "whitesmoke"=>array( "red"=>0xF5,  "green"=>0xF5,  "blue"=>0xF5), 
    "yellowgreen"=>array( "red"=>0x9A,  "green"=>0xCD,  "blue"=>0x32)
);
```

and then simply get the RGB values via `$maroon = $Colors['maroon'];`

Further reference:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#html4
- http://www.crockford.com/wrrrld/color.html

Comment: Wow, awesome! Just need to wrap it around another rgb to hex converter function!...Or just use it as it is!

Comment: In case anyone needs this function, the first contributor (Halit YEL) wrote a great function for rgb to hex on the php.net site: http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php

Comment: Link is broken. See answers below for solution.

Answer (score 30):

```
// converts an html color name to a hex color value
// if the input is not a color name, the original value is returned
// http://wpCodeSnippets.info

function color_name_to_hex($color_name)
{
    // standard 147 HTML color names
    $colors  =  array(
        'aliceblue'=>'F0F8FF',
        'antiquewhite'=>'FAEBD7',
        'aqua'=>'00FFFF',
        'aquamarine'=>'7FFFD4',
        'azure'=>'F0FFFF',
        'beige'=>'F5F5DC',
        'bisque'=>'FFE4C4',
        'black'=>'000000',
        'blanchedalmond '=>'FFEBCD',
        'blue'=>'0000FF',
        'blueviolet'=>'8A2BE2',
        'brown'=>'A52A2A',
        'burlywood'=>'DEB887',
        'cadetblue'=>'5F9EA0',
        'chartreuse'=>'7FFF00',
        'chocolate'=>'D2691E',
        'coral'=>'FF7F50',
        'cornflowerblue'=>'6495ED',
        'cornsilk'=>'FFF8DC',
        'crimson'=>'DC143C',
        'cyan'=>'00FFFF',
        'darkblue'=>'00008B',
        'darkcyan'=>'008B8B',
        'darkgoldenrod'=>'B8860B',
        'darkgray'=>'A9A9A9',
        'darkgreen'=>'006400',
        'darkgrey'=>'A9A9A9',
        'darkkhaki'=>'BDB76B',
        'darkmagenta'=>'8B008B',
        'darkolivegreen'=>'556B2F',
        'darkorange'=>'FF8C00',
        'darkorchid'=>'9932CC',
        'darkred'=>'8B0000',
        'darksalmon'=>'E9967A',
        'darkseagreen'=>'8FBC8F',
        'darkslateblue'=>'483D8B',
        'darkslategray'=>'2F4F4F',
        'darkslategrey'=>'2F4F4F',
        'darkturquoise'=>'00CED1',
        'darkviolet'=>'9400D3',
        'deeppink'=>'FF1493',
        'deepskyblue'=>'00BFFF',
        'dimgray'=>'696969',
        'dimgrey'=>'696969',
        'dodgerblue'=>'1E90FF',
        'firebrick'=>'B22222',
        'floralwhite'=>'FFFAF0',
        'forestgreen'=>'228B22',
        'fuchsia'=>'FF00FF',
        'gainsboro'=>'DCDCDC',
        'ghostwhite'=>'F8F8FF',
        'gold'=>'FFD700',
        'goldenrod'=>'DAA520',
        'gray'=>'808080',
        'green'=>'008000',
        'greenyellow'=>'ADFF2F',
        'grey'=>'808080',
        'honeydew'=>'F0FFF0',
        'hotpink'=>'FF69B4',
        'indianred'=>'CD5C5C',
        'indigo'=>'4B0082',
        'ivory'=>'FFFFF0',
        'khaki'=>'F0E68C',
        'lavender'=>'E6E6FA',
        'lavenderblush'=>'FFF0F5',
        'lawngreen'=>'7CFC00',
        'lemonchiffon'=>'FFFACD',
        'lightblue'=>'ADD8E6',
        'lightcoral'=>'F08080',
        'lightcyan'=>'E0FFFF',
        'lightgoldenrodyellow'=>'FAFAD2',
        'lightgray'=>'D3D3D3',
        'lightgreen'=>'90EE90',
        'lightgrey'=>'D3D3D3',
        'lightpink'=>'FFB6C1',
        'lightsalmon'=>'FFA07A',
        'lightseagreen'=>'20B2AA',
        'lightskyblue'=>'87CEFA',
        'lightslategray'=>'778899',
        'lightslategrey'=>'778899',
        'lightsteelblue'=>'B0C4DE',
        'lightyellow'=>'FFFFE0',
        'lime'=>'00FF00',
        'limegreen'=>'32CD32',
        'linen'=>'FAF0E6',
        'magenta'=>'FF00FF',
        'maroon'=>'800000',
        'mediumaquamarine'=>'66CDAA',
        'mediumblue'=>'0000CD',
        'mediumorchid'=>'BA55D3',
        'mediumpurple'=>'9370D0',
        'mediumseagreen'=>'3CB371',
        'mediumslateblue'=>'7B68EE',
        'mediumspringgreen'=>'00FA9A',
        'mediumturquoise'=>'48D1CC',
        'mediumvioletred'=>'C71585',
        'midnightblue'=>'191970',
        'mintcream'=>'F5FFFA',
        'mistyrose'=>'FFE4E1',
        'moccasin'=>'FFE4B5',
        'navajowhite'=>'FFDEAD',
        'navy'=>'000080',
        'oldlace'=>'FDF5E6',
        'olive'=>'808000',
        'olivedrab'=>'6B8E23',
        'orange'=>'FFA500',
        'orangered'=>'FF4500',
        'orchid'=>'DA70D6',
        'palegoldenrod'=>'EEE8AA',
        'palegreen'=>'98FB98',
        'paleturquoise'=>'AFEEEE',
        'palevioletred'=>'DB7093',
        'papayawhip'=>'FFEFD5',
        'peachpuff'=>'FFDAB9',
        'peru'=>'CD853F',
        'pink'=>'FFC0CB',
        'plum'=>'DDA0DD',
        'powderblue'=>'B0E0E6',
        'purple'=>'800080',
        'red'=>'FF0000',
        'rosybrown'=>'BC8F8F',
        'royalblue'=>'4169E1',
        'saddlebrown'=>'8B4513',
        'salmon'=>'FA8072',
        'sandybrown'=>'F4A460',
        'seagreen'=>'2E8B57',
        'seashell'=>'FFF5EE',
        'sienna'=>'A0522D',
        'silver'=>'C0C0C0',
        'skyblue'=>'87CEEB',
        'slateblue'=>'6A5ACD',
        'slategray'=>'708090',
        'slategrey'=>'708090',
        'snow'=>'FFFAFA',
        'springgreen'=>'00FF7F',
        'steelblue'=>'4682B4',
        'tan'=>'D2B48C',
        'teal'=>'008080',
        'thistle'=>'D8BFD8',
        'tomato'=>'FF6347',
        'turquoise'=>'40E0D0',
        'violet'=>'EE82EE',
        'wheat'=>'F5DEB3',
        'white'=>'FFFFFF',
        'whitesmoke'=>'F5F5F5',
        'yellow'=>'FFFF00',
        'yellowgreen'=>'9ACD32');

    $color_name = strtolower($color_name);
    if (isset($colors[$color_name]))
    {
        return ('#' . $colors[$color_name]);
    }
    else
    {
        return ($color_name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In 2024, the seemingly simple problem remains unanswered...simple
My contribution will be in the form of a mysql table which could solve this 'thorny problem' here is the structure

```
 -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.2.1
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Hôte : 127.0.0.1
-- Généré le : jeu. 11 jan. 2024 à 11:32
-- Version du serveur : 10.4.28-MariaDB
-- Version de PHP : 8.2.4

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

--
-- Base de données : `xxxxx`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure de la table `css2hex`
--

CREATE TABLE `css2hex` (
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `hex` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

--
-- Déchargement des données de la table `css2hex`
--

INSERT INTO `css2hex` (`name`, `hex`) VALUES
('AliceBlue', '#F0F8FF'),
('AntiqueWhite', '#FAEBD7'),
('Aqua', '#00FFFF'),
('Aquamarine', '#7FFFD4'),
('Azure', '#F0FFFF'),
('Beige', '#F5F5DC'),
('Bisque', '#FFE4C4'),
('Black', '#000000'),
('BlanchedAlmond', '#FFEBCD'),
('Blue', '#0000FF'),
('BlueViolet', '#8A2BE2'),
('Brown', '#A52A2A'),
('BurlyWood', '#DEB887'),
('CadetBlue', '#5F9EA0'),
('Chartreuse', '#7FFF00'),
('Chocolate', '#D2691E'),
('Coral', '#FF7F50'),
('CornflowerBlue', '#6495ED'),
('Cornsilk', '#FFF8DC'),
('Crimson', '#DC143C'),
('Cyan', '#00FFFF'),
('DarkBlue', '#00008B'),
('DarkCyan', '#008B8B'),
('DarkGoldenrod', '#B8860B'),
('DarkGray', '#A9A9A9'),
('DarkGreen', '#006400'),
('DarkGrey', '#A9A9A9'),
('DarkKhaki', '#BDB76B'),
('DarkMagenta', '#8B008B'),
('DarkOliveGreen', '#556B2F'),
('DarkOrange', '#FF8C00'),
('DarkOrchid', '#9932CC'),
('DarkRed', '#8B0000'),
('DarkSalmon', '#E9967A'),
('DarkSeaGreen', '#8FBC8F'),
('DarkSlateBlue', '#483D8B'),
('DarkSlateGray', '#2F4F4F'),
('DarkSlateGrey', '#2F4F4F'),
('DarkTurquoise', '#00CED1'),
('DarkViolet', '#9400D3'),
('DeepPink', '#FF1493'),
('DeepSkyBlue', '#00BFFF'),
('DimGray', '#696969'),
('DodgerBlue', '#1E90FF'),
('FireBrick', '#B22222'),
('FloralWhite', '#FFFAF0'),
('ForestGreen', '#228B22'),
('Fuchsia', '#FF00FF'),
('Gainsboro', '#DCDCDC'),
('GhostWhite', '#F8F8FF'),
('Gold', '#FFD700'),
('Goldenrod', '#DAA520'),
('Gray', '#808080'),
('Green', '#008000'),
('GreenYellow', '#ADFF2F'),
('Grey', '#808080'),
('Honeydew', '#F0FFF0'),
('HotPink', '#FF69B4'),
('IndianRed', '#CD5C5C'),
('Indigo', '#4B0082'),
('Ivory', '#FFFFF0'),
('Khaki', '#F0E68C'),
('Lavender', '#E6E6FA'),
('LavenderBlush', '#FFF0F5'),
('LawnGreen', '#7CFC00'),
('LemonChiffon', '#FFFACD'),
('LightBlue', '#ADD8E6'),
('LightCoral', '#F08080'),
('LightCyan', '#E0FFFF'),
('LightGoldenrodYellow', '#FAFAD2'),
('LightGray', '#D3D3D3'),
('LightGreen', '#90EE90'),
('LightGrey', '#D3D3D3'),
('LightPink', '#FFB6C1'),
('LightSalmon', '#FFA07A'),
('LightSeaGreen', '#20B2AA'),
('LightSkyBlue', '#87CEFA'),
('LightSlateGray', '#778899'),
('LightSlateGrey', '#778899'),
('LightSteelBlue', '#B0C4DE'),
('LightYellow', '#FFFFE0'),
('Lime', '#00FF00'),
('LimeGreen', '#32CD32'),
('Linen', '#FAF0E6'),
('Magenta', '#FF00FF'),
('Maroon', '#800000'),
('MediumAquamarine', '#66CDAA'),
('MediumBlue', '#0000CD'),
('MediumOrchid', '#BA55D3'),
('MediumPurple', '#9370D0'),
('MediumSeaGreen', '#3CB371'),
('MediumSlateBlue', '#7B68EE'),
('MediumSpringGreen', '#00FA9A'),
('MediumTurquoise', '#48D1CC'),
('MediumVioletRed', '#C71585'),
('MidnightBlue', '#191970'),
('MintCream', '#F5FFFA'),
('MistyRose', '#FFE4E1'),
('Moccasin', '#FFE4B5'),
('NavajoWhite', '#FFDEAD'),
('Navy', '#000080'),
('OldLace', '#FDF5E6'),
('Olive', '#808000'),
('OliveDrab', '#6B8E23'),
('Orange', '#FFA500'),
('OrangeRed', '#FF4500'),
('Orchid', '#DA70D6'),
('PaleGoldenrod', '#EEE8AA'),
('PaleGreen', '#98FB98'),
('PaleTurquoise', '#AFEEEE'),
('PaleVioletRed', '#DB7093'),
('PapayaWhip', '#FFEFD5'),
('PeachPuff', '#FFDAB9'),
('Peru', '#CD853F'),
('Pink', '#FFC0CB'),
('Plum', '#DDA0DD'),
('PowderBlue', '#B0E0E6'),
('Purple', '#800080'),
('Rebeccapurple', '#663399'),
('Red', '#FF0000'),
('RosyBrown', '#BC8F8F'),
('RoyalBlue', '#4169E1'),
('SaddleBrown', '#8B4513'),
('Salmon', '#FA8072'),
('SandyBrown', '#F4A460'),
('SeaGreen', '#2E8B57'),
('Seashell', '#FFF5EE'),
('Sienna', '#A0522D'),
('Silver', '#C0C0C0'),
('SkyBlue', '#87CEEB'),
('SlateBlue', '#6A5ACD'),
('SlateGray', '#708090'),
('SlateGrey', '#708090'),
('Snow', '#FFFAFA'),
('SpringGreen', '#00FF7F'),
('SteelBlue', '#4682B4'),
('Tan', '#D2B48C'),
('Teal', '#008080'),
('Thistle', '#D8BFD8'),
('Tomato', '#FF6347'),
('Turquoise', '#40E0D0'),
('Violet', '#EE82EE'),
('Wheat', '#F5DEB3'),
('White', '#FFFFFF'),
('WhiteSmoke', '#F5F5F5'),
('Yellow', '#FFFF00'),
('YellowGreen', '#9ACD32');
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Copying all of the data from the top voted answer and re-writing it as a table may be a sensible technique for you but adds a lot of redundundant content to this page.