# How to convert color name to the corresponding hexadecimal representation in php?

Tags: php, colors

I have a variable ($color) which cointains values of color names, 'orange', 'red', etc.
I don't know how to convert these values to hexadecimal, because I need the hexadecimal values for another function.

For example:

Convert:

```
black
```

To:

```
#000000
```

---

I also need to check if the color is a color name or a value in hexadecimal...

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you looked at any of the *likely duplicate questions* over there on the Related sidebar?  This is quite literally as easy as getting the list of CSS color codes, building a hash, and looking things up... Well, that is unless you want to replicate browser behavior when given *invalid* colors, in which case speak up *now*, as that's a completely different thing.

Comment: Make an array map, `$colorname_to_hex = array("black"=>"#000000")`. Then look up the names with a trivial array access.

Comment: see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553566/how-to-convert-a-string-color-to-its-hex-code-or-rgb-value)

Comment: OK, sorry for the duplicate question, but now I need a function to check if the color is in hexadecimal or is a color name.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to take a look at :

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#html4

store the string names and corresponding hex values in Database or in array and when converting just pull hex value from database or array that has the given keyname.