# Converting color name to hexadecimal values

Tags: html, css, color-codes

In order to perform the conversion I followed a Stack Overflow post below which gave an idea how the conversions are taking place and colors are shown by browser

But when I checked with following examples:

```
<body bgcolor="a">
10,0,0
#0A 00 00


<body bgcolor="marker">
10,0,224
#0A 00 E0


<body bgcolor="kevineve">
224,14,224
#E00EE0
```

Same rule did not help me find the exact values for `kevineve` `#E00EE0`

> What are the rules to convert a color name to its hex value ?

Color name can be any value: like below post or just any alphabet

Stack Overflow post:
[Why does HTML think “chucknorris” is a color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color)

**Note:** please note hex converted values of: `a` and `kevineve`

Comment: I think your answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573053/javascript-function-to-convert-color-names-to-hex-codes). Similar question.

Comment: @user2584538 no its not similar here no real color names are taken into account

Comment: you can use a DB storage or array like something. isn't that possible for you..?

Comment: we cannot store every value in db know..Color name can be any value : SO post mentioned or just any alphabet

Comment: @utility: You may want to check this out -- http://randomstringtocsscolor.com/ and the complete set of rules from the HTML5 specs are here - https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-microsyntaxes.html#colors

Comment: @Abhitalks cannot load that site .. is that site live ?

Comment: @utility Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553566/how-to-convert-a-string-color-to-its-hex-code-or-rgb-value

Comment: @utility: Yes. Just checked.

Comment: thank you @Abhitalks , it seems there is an algorithm for the same at : https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-microsyntaxes.html#colors ..let me work out the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does HTML think “chucknorris” is a color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color)

Comment: @dippas no post is not a duplicate one , that particular post focused on a particular word

Comment: your kevineve is well converted to rgb and hex.

Comment: @dippas but the hex value is different from that stated in that SO post know

Comment: @utility see my answer